# text-decoration CSS being overridden on Safari for iPad/iPhone

Tags: iphone, css, ipad, debugging, safari

Annoying little bug... have found that despite specifying `{text-decoration:none;}` on links in my stylesheet, Safari on iPhone and iPad is ignoring this, and underlining links.

Totally fine on web Safari/Ffox/Chrome etc... just the iPad/iPhone.

Any tips? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding !Important to your CSS. This will override any other styles and force it to use what you have specified.

```
{text-decoration:none !Important;}
```

Comment: He should be more [specific](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/), but `!important` is a cheap hack.